# When add second product, custom attributes not save data. Using event " sales_quote_item_set_product " in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, sales-quote

I used the `sales_quote_item_set_product` event to save data to the table when adding to cart product. It works but when I add the next product, it does not save the old data in the old field.

My observer

```
$quoteItem = $observer->getQuoteItem();
$product = $observer->getProduct();
$quoteItem->setAllowedAge($product->getData('age_status'));
```

Add first product, my data like this

[image]

Add second product, my data like this

[image]

Comment: I solved using checkout_cart_product_add_after. Thank for all

Answer (score 0):

At magento, the event `sales_quote_item_set_product` is not only fire when adding to a product is adding to cart .it is always fire when quote object is load.

As you want to fire then event only add to cart then you have to add `quote_item_id`  column.

If a `quote_item` already exist then it cannot perform the operation.In this way, you can avoid this issue.

Comment: I solved using checkout_cart_product_add_after. Thank for all